# Connect to a remote server and use the remote collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two applications to be deployed seperately, but partially sharing a database and users. I created a pretty simple method to connect.

```
Remote.connect = function (remoteUrl="http://localhost:3030") {
  let remote = DDP.connect(remoteUrl);
  Meteor.remote = remote;
  Accounts.connection = remote;
  Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection('users', {
    connection = remote
  });
  return remote;
}

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Remote.connect(Meteor.settings.public.REMOTE_URL);
});
```

So this will work -- I can log in as a "remote" user just as easily. However, I am having some trouble using other collections. For example:

```
Orders = new Mongo.Collection('orders', {
  connection: Meteor.remote
});
```

This shares the same name as my "orders" collection on the remote application. I try to query it on my local but it does not yield any results. If I query it on the main application, it yields one result.

How can I connect to remote collections with meteor?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to your other app's publication with `Meteor.remote.subscribe()` ?

Comment: that worked! you should put it as an answer so I can give you points for it

Comment: Good to hear! Answer submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your "client" app's collection to be populated with your "server" app's collection data, you will need to subscribe to this app's publication. The object returned by `DDP.connect()` [can help you do just that](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddp_connect). Say your original app publishes orders this way:

```
Meteor.publish('orders', function () {
  return Orders.find();
});
```

Then all you need to do in order to populate your client app is:

```
Meteor.remote.subscribe('orders');
```